# Updating OneSignal dependency getting unable to resolve dependency error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, onesignal, gradle-plugin

Unable to resolve dependency while updating OneSignal dependency

After updating my gradle from

```
classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.8.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.9.0, 0.99.99]'
```

getting error below like this

its working fine with

```
classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.8.1'
```

[image]

App Level Gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.9.0, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en","ta"
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug{
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }



}

dependencies {

    ext {
        support_library_version = '27.1.1'
        google_play_services_version = '15.0.1'
    }


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1'


    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'



}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project Level gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: @vm345 gradle files posted

Comment: can you check whether offline work is enabled in android studio

Comment: offline work is not enable in my android studio

Comment: Then I think in this line implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1 there is a mistake. You missed a symbol ' in the end

Comment: that's not a issue its an edit problem

Comment: Try to upgrade google-services classpath to 3.2.1 like: 
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

Comment: @Paraskevas Ntsounos is not working remains same

Comment: @SarathKumar try my updated answer, i think this help your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the files below, it works for me:

App Level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "xxx",
                                onesignal_app_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en","ta"
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug{
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }



}

dependencies {

    ext {
        support_library_version = '27.1.1'
        google_play_services_version = '15.0.0'
    }

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1'


    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project Level gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

I hope this help.